# Get installed version of only the packages specified in a requirement

Tags: pip, package, version

How can I get the installed versions of packages that are specified in a `requirements.txt` and only those specified?

`pip freeze` outputs everything that's installed on my local system, while I only want those given in the requirement.

For example, assume the TXT file contains only one line of `pytest>=3.5.0`, and I install packages using the following commands:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install numpy
```

How can I get information like `pytest==3.5.1` without revealing information like `numpy==1.14.3`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way other than processing `requirements.txt` line by
line:

```
while read line; do
    pip show `echo $line | sed 's/[<>=].\+//'`
done < requirements.txt
```

The output format is, alas, different from `pip freeze` but the output can be process further.

Comment: nope. All packages have a version specifier which would break `pip show`

Comment: Then remove it during reading of `requirements.txt`. I updated the answer to show an example.